# Merging disparate database queries into a single query

Tags: laravel

I have a function called `image()` that takes some parameters and then performs a database query to retrieve a `File` record, which is then used to generate the url. This function is used in multiple places within a view e.g.

```
<body>

    <div>
        <img src="{{ image("asset1") }}" />
    </div>

    ... more html ...

    <div>
        <img src="{{ image("asset2") }}" />
    </div>  

    ... more html ...

    <div>
        <img src="{{ image("asset3") }}" />
    </div>   
</body>
```

The above code would execute 3 database queries, but depending on the number of `image` method calls, it could end up being 10, 15, 20 etc. I also have no way of knowing in advance which assets are going to be requested.

I'm looking to find a way to essentially "merge" each of these `image` method calls / group all of the queries into one to improve performance. However, I'm not quite sure of the best approach to use for this.

I thought about having the `image` method return a piece of placeholder text and then, after the view is rendered, executing the query and performing a find and replace within the HTML? Is that the right way to go? Practical? Performant?

Any suggestions / recommendations would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Make no changes until you measure performance. Then make a plan and check effect. Possible ordering: emit appropriate caching headers, so the client won't request the same image if it hasn't changed. Use a CDN to front the installation, so your compute resources aren't impinged at all. After those changes, if it's still an issue, cache the images in a key store. If it's still an issue, optimize your code to make one database request, storing the results some place convenient, then using a different helper to pull from that convenient location rather than the database.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I think maybe I didn’t make it clear. It’s not so much about caching the images, as much as it is running the queries in order to get the urls themselves.

Comment: Have you considered a query builder of sorts? An object which you can add images to one at a time and after all images have been added, you can turn it into an actual query. The result of the query can be used in the view.

Comment: Maybe the relevant controller and image source code could help in the optimization process to see which query are you performing

Comment: I like the idea of a query builder, however since the builder would be built up in the view itself, how would you be able to execute it prior to the view being rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial strategy seems to be a suitable approach. I ended up using View creators to manipulate the rendered HTML before it is delivered to the user.

See https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views#view-composers